# Firebase analytics bot filtering?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

Yesterday I set up Firebase analytics and crash reporting with custom logs in my app. I published that apk to Play Store alpha testing and downloaded it from my two devices.

Now, about 12 hours later, I see my custom events in the dashboard but most of the traffic seems to be coming from the USA instead of Serbia, where I'm located (5.5% - 94.5%).

Obviously, this is caused by the bot traffic from Google Play, I've had this issue before when using the Google Analytics, and it was easy to overcome because it had the "Bot filtering" option.

I can't seem to find any similar setting in the Firebase console, and also this traffic wasn't visible in the Fabric Crashlytics/Answers.

Are there any solutions to this issue? Google search doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Firebase Analytics doesn't currently have this "Bot filtering" option. The team is aware of the issue and it's something they would like to address, but I don't have any timeline for a fix at this time. Sorry!